# PCA explained variance and model inertia

Tags: k-means, pca, variance, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to perform a PCA to reduce the dimensionality of my data and subsequently perform a K-Means algorithm.

I initially chose 4 Principal Components because they explain 70% of my variance. This, however, leads to model inertia of roughly 1500.

With only 2 Principal Components -- that explain 55% of my variance -- the model inertia is only 600.

How do I find the balance between these two measurements, namely explained variance and model inertia? What should I prioritize? Should I do something completely different?

Comment: You should define what is inertia in your question. Word Inertia is defined differently in different areas of analysis or in different textbooks.